# DOB Collection from PHP to PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, phpmyadmin

I have never collected DOB before.  This is the first time i am doing it.

What is the best way to first of all collect dob from the php form?

Do i allow them to enter it as 12/03/1979 or something like 12031979.

And do i need 3 fields in the db like month, day, and year?

And then for the db, what do i select for the type, date?   I want to be able to reuse this data for research purposes later.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean Date of Birth?

You will use DATE as datatype.

For the GUI, I suggest using three dropdown boxes: Year, Month and Day. Use 4 digits for years and month names (rather than numbers) to make it crystal clear.

Under no circumstances let the user enter a date in a text field, because you won't be able to parse it correctly afterwards.

Comment: yes, i mean date of birth.  sorry for the confusion. so do i need to have 3 boxes in the db, like month/day/year?? thx

Comment: No he does not mean that, he means run a query like so: `INSERT INTO Table DOB (DATE(year-month-day))` I believe.

Comment: @RobertPitt Thanks.  OK. How do i do this via the php form?